# Can I have 100A main breaker with 100A main panel for solar panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, subpanel, solar-panels

I have an inverter with 21A output current. And will existing 100A main busbar with existing 100A center fed main breaker?

I was looking online and there are articles about NEC rules for center fed main breaker. The rule states that:

"A connection at either end, but not both ends, of a center-fed panelboard in dwellings shall be permitted where the sum of 125 percent of the power source(s) output circuit current and the rating of the overcurrent device protecting the busbar does not exceed 120 percent of the current rating of the busbar."

So if I am reading it correctly, I am getting:

- 125% x 21A = 26.25A
- OCPD(is this the same as the main breaker?) = 100A
- sum = 126.25A
- 120% x 100A= 120A

So since 120A < 126.25A, then it is not good? It says PV Breaker is 30A.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Why do you believe the panel has a 100A main bus-bar?  Did you actually read it off the panel labeling?  Does the labeling have any kit or instructions to convert to 125A main breaker?  (we only care if that's an option, we're not going to actually do it).

Comment: I am just trying to understand the NEC rules with my calculations. If I am understanding what NEC is saying based on the given information.

Comment: If this is a *hypothetical*, then you are correct IMO.  If this is a real-world case, please post a clear photo of the panel labeling and we'll see if we can tease some more capacity out of it.

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel door please, or is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: Yes, this is a hypothetical question. I just wanted to understand the NEC rule I highlighted.